# refresh gridview after search

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a search on a grid view which limits the results. I would like the grid view to repopulate with all entries if a. the search box is empty or b. the user hits a button to refresh.

```
Protected Sub btnSeach_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSeach.Click
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataSourceID = ""
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataSource = ObjectDataSource1
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind()


    If txtFnameSearch.text = " " Then
        StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnRefreshSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefreshSearch.Click
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind()
End Sub
End Class
```

StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind() obviously doesn't work.

how do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to repopulate the GridView is by having a method specifically for binding your data and calling when needed.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostback)
        BindGrid();
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataSource = ObjectDataSource1;
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind();

}

protected void btnRefreshSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid(); 
}

protected void btnSeach_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFnameSearch.text))
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you are filtering your data directly via the ObjectDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the datasource again and set it as the DataSource and then bind again.

Something like this

```
Protected Sub btnRefreshSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefreshSearch.Click

    Dim searchKey as String 
    searchKey  =txtFnameSearch.Text.Trim()
    Dim staffSearchREsults=MyService.GetSearchResults(searchKey)
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataSource = staffSearchREsults
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Assuming `MyService.GetSearchResults` method will return you a valid search result based on the search key.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because, after postback, gridview's datasource will be lost. So you always need to set datasource before DataBind() is called.

```
StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataSource = ObjectDataSource1
StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind()
```

You can also save ObjectDataSource1 into session and use it later for binding:

```
Session["MyObjectDataSource"] = ObjectDataSource1;
```

...

```
Protected Sub btnRefreshSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefreshSearch.Click
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataSource = Session["MyObjectDataSource"]
    StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a declarative datasource, you can just call `DataBind()` again on the `GridView`:

```
StaffDetailsStaffGridView.DataBind()
```